# How to use Public IP's for onclick function in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I intend to use the Public IP from different users available on the internet and use their public IP for onClick function in my app. Is there any way to make that possible? I am trying to create a multi-player game like tick tack toe in which two people can play over internet, I want to use the onClick function to change the image using the public ip of the users available to capture the responses.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? There's a million libraries for this if you don't have the skills, otherwise [Minimum requirements for a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am new to multi-player programming, I have been experimenting with ImageView.

 `<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="gameLogic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />`

Comment: What has your image view got to do with IP?

Comment: I am not sure how to use ip to get input for onClick function?

Comment: so I was trying to use this code with imageView:
`public void gameLogic(View view){
    ImageView tappedView = (ImageView) view;
    tappedView.setTranslationY(-3000f);
    tappedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.crossed);
    tappedView.animate().translationYBy(3000f).setDuration(500);
}`

Comment: These are separate things. Break it down into logical steps. You need to detect a click, do something to the game, show it on your own device THEN broadcast it to other players

Comment: okay, so I can do this by implementing an online database and by setting up a client server connection right?

Comment: Why would you need an online database? You need to do some research on various types of connections. A shared server or push would be simplest yes

Comment: Okay, I will look into the shared server or push. Thank you for the help.